# Cannot figure out which NGINX config file is being used

Tags: nginx, configuration, subdomain, web-hosting

Inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available`, I have a config file `example` with the following configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name php1.example.com php2.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.key;

    root /var/www/html/example/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; # Adjust the PHP version if needed
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example_access.log;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    server_name admin.php1.example.com;

    root /var/www/html/example/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock; # Adjust the PHP version if needed
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/example_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example_access.log;
}
```

This serves a PHP website which is setup in a way to connect to different databases for different subdomains.
I am using Cloudflare and could not setup SSL for the multi-level subdomain `admin.php1.example.com`.
I have pointed `php1.example.com`, `php2.example.com`, `php3.example.com` and `admin.php1.example.com` to my server's IP, but have not included `php3.example.com` in my config file.

The issue is, when I go to `php3.example.com` in my browser, it loads up the website even though it is not configured in the config file. I cannot figure out which config file is being used to serve the website.

Since it was working as intended for the other subdomains, I ignored it.

Until now, when I had to setup a Node.js project on the same server. I wrote another config file `node-project.conf` with the following configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name node.example.com;

        # location / {
        #       proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        #       proxy_http_version 1.1;
        #       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        #       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        #       proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #       proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        # }

        location / {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html;
                index index.html index.htm;
        }
}
```

I am trying to serve NGINX's default welcome page to test if my new subdomain `node.example.com` is correctly pointed to my IP.
But when I visited the subdomain in my browser, I got served the same PHP website that was being served for `php3.example.com`.

I am new to this, but am passionate about server administration. I want to fix this issue as well as understand what is happening behind the scene, so I can become a better admin.

I am also new to Server Fault. I have tried my best to make the question as descriptive as possible, but if anybody wants additional information regarding anything, please let me know.

In `sites-available`, I have `default` config with following configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx default host when not defined](https://serverfault.com/questions/432647/nginx-default-host-when-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nginx -T`. In my case it shows this

```
$ nginx -T | grep "# config*"
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:
# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:
```

Keep in mind that you need to symlink to sites-enabled to activate a conf file for nginx and reload

---

You can either grep through /etc/nginx recursively and see if you can find a match for any of the conf files which has a value php3.example.com

```
grep -r "php3.example.com" /etc/nginx
```

Or only through sites-enabled and sites-available

```
grep -r "php3.example.com" /etc/nginx/sites-enabled /etc/nginx/sites-available
```

---

You could enable access logging in the main nginx config (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf)

```
http {
    # Other configurations...
log_format custom_format '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
                        'vhost:$server_name';

    # Enable logging
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log custom_format;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    # Other configurations...
}
```

And then you could grep through those logs if there is a hit for php3.example.com

```
grep 'php3.example.com' /var/log/nginx/access.log
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does it do and how does it solve the problem?

Comment: Nginx -t is to test /show the running nginx config and then i grep the output for conf files

Comment: I ran `nginx -t` and it was okay. I also did the symlink thing.

Comment: nginx -T also generates output, each configuration file that is active has above it # configuration file

Comment: It shows there is nothing wrong with the config and a list of config files. What I want is to understand why is my issue occurring and a way to fix it.

Comment: I created an chat room that's easier https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/151582/https-serverfault-com-questions-1154012-cannot-figure-out-which-nginx-config-fi?tab=general

Comment: @UvaisHassan I edited my post, because you can't enter the chat